# Problems mining ether on GTX 970

Tags: mining, ether, gpu

I would like to start mining ether, but I am running into a big problem. I have a EVGA gtx 970 that works fine in games and benchmarks, however it only runs at about 2 mh/s compared to the 15+ I see others getting who mine with the same card. It is not a temperature issue as the card only runs at about 60c at its hottest when mining and the card is not over/under clocked. I have used all recommended drivers as well as several different mining programs, all of which resulted in a similar range of 1.5-3mh/s. In all of the configs the servers are set to the location nearest to me and the parameters are set to 100%. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: bumping this post

Answer (score 1):

Goog news for you. I had exactly the same problem and I solved it (before: 3MH/s, now: 19MH/s).

Solution:

1. Install the old nvidia driver version number 347.52
2. Download ethminer 1.1.7 here: https://github.com/Genoil/cpp-ethereum/blob/master/releases/ethminer-0.9.41-genoil-1.1.7.zip
3. Launch ethminer with the following cmd line:

   ```
   ethminer.exe --farm-recheck 200 -G -F {httpAddressOfThePool}/0x51EF8391854a30BEcaEa5f1635e7966276636d58
   ```

Tell me if it works.